# ASP.NET MVC with Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to develop an app with ASP.NET MVC Mono.
Installed latest version of Mono and Monodevelop. While trying to run a default "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC on Mono!" app I get the following errors:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 34:               Line 35:                  Line 36:               Line 37:               Line 38:
>
> Source File: C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\mvc\mvc\web.config    Line: 36
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927

Tried putting System.Web.Mvc.dll from C:\Program Files\Mono-2.10.6\lib\mono\2.0 to bin\ - app still doesn't run, I just get

> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

instead of

> The system cannot find the file specified.

What should I do?

P.S. My OS is Windows 7.

Comment: Try running it with mono (not .NET) after copying. MonoDevelop runs with .net as default.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, I'm posting this as an answer ;) When trying to run application which references Mono's assemblies, one can try running it with Mono (not .NET what MonoDevelop does as default) as it uses different GAC.

Comment: Could you explain how to run ASP.NET application with Mono instead of .NET? And is there way to set Mono as default in MonoDevelop?

Comment: @MarisKs: yes, if you've installed Mono on Windows, there should be listbox on the top of the main window which lets you choose current runtime for the project (Mono or .NET). There also may be a preference setting which runtime to use for the new projects, I'm not sure (and using Linux ;)).